# Can't install PHP Intl on CentOS 6.5

Tags: php, packages, centos6.5

I'm trying to install this package on my server running PHP 5.4 with no success. However, it only took a few seconds on my PC running OpenSUSE 13.2. The name of the package was "php5-intl-5.6.1-18.1.x86_64", but running "yum search" on the server doesn't return anything containing both the terms "php" and "intl".

I installed and enabled the "remi" and "remiphp55" repositories but it doesn't help neither. I still can't find the packages.

Is there any way how I can install the package?

Answer (score 1):

On Red Hat-based systems the package name is `php-intl`.

```
Available Packages
Name        : php-intl
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 5.5.23
Release     : 1.el7.remi
Size        : 213 k
Repo        : remi-php55
Summary     : Internationalization extension for PHP applications
URL         : http://www.php.net/
License     : PHP
Description : The php-intl package contains a dynamic shared object that will
            : add support for using the ICU library to PHP.
```